# U.S. Speaker Johnson says the house will take up Ukrainian aid in next few weeks

Tags: united-states, ukraine, house-of-representatives, legislative-process, foreign-aid

The House is out of session, and holding a Republican strategy, team building retreat at the Green Briar Hotel in West Virginia. Yesterday Speaker Johnson announced at the retreat that the house would take up, Ukrainian aid vote in the next two weeks.

**[Johnson says he expects the house take up Ukraine aid with Democratic votes](https://www.politico.com/news/2024/03/14/mike-johnson-israel-ukraine-aid-bill-00147108)**

So what happened?

What is the "suspension calendar"?  and what changed to allow the Dems?  to leverage it?

Senate has already passed the 93 billion package, do they start there?

Comment: Sounds like they made a deal

Comment: or maybe unrelated, and they want to unbundle the Israel aid portion, to make room for further haggling ... https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/other/johnson-considering-stand-alone-israel-aid-bill-following-comments-from-schumer-on-foreign-ally-s-elections/ar-BB1jUnZ5 ... or both.

Comment: in same link, Schumer made what is for him unprecedented criticism of Israel, essentially calling for Netanyahu's defenestration

Comment: @PeteW,  Take back my previous comment.  Evidently the suspension calendar is something Johnson has used in the past to pass non - controversial bills.  And the article says Johnson expects to pass the bill.  So clearly he is supporting it.   I noticed he seemed to nod in approval at the State of the Union speech when Biden lead off with how important Ukrainian aid was.

Comment: We'll see soon.

Comment: @PeteW,  yeah you're right.  There was definitely a deal done.   First order of business is to keep the U.S. government funded, and deadline March 28th,  and directly after that Foreign aid.

Comment: yeah, looking at some more statements, it sure looks like they have a deal on both Ukraine and Israel

Comment: @PeteW, and amazingly Speaker Johnson, is not in fear of being removed from the speakership, is the one putting the vote on the docket through the Suspension Calendar which he alone controls and seems to be personally supporting the bill.   It's all fascinating.

Answer (score 6):

Re: Suspension motion

> Members frequently use the “motion to suspend the rules” to fast-track legislation that has broad support and little need for prolonged debate. When the House considers a bill under suspension of the rules, the House suspends its normal rules and procedures controlling legislative debate and votes, allowing the bill to pass quickly. The suspension process’ parameters mean that broadly bipartisan legislation is typically best suited for it.
> from: https://www.progressivecaucuscenter.org/suspensions-117th-congress

Re: Suspension calendar

There is a special calendar when a suspension motion may be made.

> A motion to suspend the rules may only be made by the Speaker of the
> House or their designee, though it is customary for committee chairs
> to write the Speaker requesting a suspension. Once a member moves to
> "suspend the rules" and take some action, debate is limited to 40
> minutes, no amendments can be offered to the motion or the underlying
> matter, and a 2/3 majority of Members present and voting is required
> to agree to the motion.
>
> These votes, under the rules, may only take place on Mondays,
> Tuesdays, and Wednesdays. Under special circumstances, suspension
> votes may take place on Thursdays or Fridays, or other days...
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_the_rules_in_the_United_States_Congress

I think the Speaker is really just saying, that he plans on bringing the new bill to the floor via a suspension motion.

Potential significance in the current situation:

- If the matter under consideration was controversial, like Ukraine aid, it would be a sign that a deal was made between the party leaders, and they're using procedure to limit debate for the purpose of locking out any hold-outs still opposed to the deal.
- If the matter under consideration was not particularly controversial (eg Israel aid, without the House IRS policy changes bundled to it), it wouldn't mean much.

Comment: It's worth nothing that after (standalone) aid to Israel [failed](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84554/why-could-the-house-get-250-180-votes-on-some-bill-but-not-muster-the-simple-ma) to reach the 2/3 votes, Johnson said he would bring it to the floor in regular procedure "next week", but AFAICT that hasn't happened in over a month. So the hardliners in the rules committee stuck to their guns apparently. Johnson may be getting tired of them.

Comment: OTOH he may also be counting on the fact that there's more opposition in the GOP to Ukraine aid, so maybe he's done the math that Ukraine aid will also fail to reach 2/3, IDK.

Comment: Thirdly, on Ukraine aid, he was threatened with his decision being bypassed entirely via a discharge petition. https://kyivindependent.com/us-congress-may-start-gathering-votes-to-bypass-speaker-johnson-on-ukraine-aid/ I'm not sure how realistic the chances for that were though. And we can only speculate if Johnson's  decision was somehow influenced by that.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat yeah there's a lot going on. Another factor is that the bulk of the primaries are done, so the pressure is off many Representatives among those who were worried about that.

Comment: Schumer's statement yesterday is also a factor that reflects Israel policy into the US election maneuverings, because of the Netanyahu - Trump alliance. Many Republicans in both House and Senate seem to have responded to that. I'm really unclear about the logic of where that goes.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat: I'd say the odds of a discharge petition being successful are greater than the odds of Putin ally Mike Johnson actually allowing a meaningful Ukraine aid bill to come to the floor.